# Qt Interface freeze on background task

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtcore

I have an entertaining problem to solve. I use Qt 5 for one of my projects for reading information on the network. I read modbus devices and stuff, but the real problem comes when the network isn't available.

The interface freezes and I can't interact with it. The network stuff is done in a separate thread or that is what I think. Here is some code example:

```
class TwidoDevice : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TwidoDevice
........ And some useful code
```

The use of the (main interface) class in `Window.cpp` is:

```
L1Thread = new QThread();
L1Thread->start();
L1TWD = new TwidoDevice(L1TWD_settings,
                        L1TWD_Name,
                        PercentRegisters,
                        TotalsRegisters,
                        db, 1);
L1TWD->moveToThread(L1Thread);
connect(this, SIGNAL(startReading()), L1TWD, SLOT(startFired()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

In this code `startFired()` start reading the devices on the network.

In some other function in `Window.cpp`:

```
emit startReading()
```

When this code is executed the interface freezes even though I've moved the `L1TWD` object to `QThread`.

When I try to debug it using the built-in debugger in QtCreator, I can't seem to understand whether the object has been moved or not and why the interface is frozen during the network call.

Has any one encountered the same problem and what is the way to solve this?

Thank you for spending time reading my question!

Comment: Have you tried `connect(this, SIGNAL(startReading()), L1TWD, SLOT(startFired()));`? Please use currentThread to print this out to make sure that you moved properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the main problem:

> connect(this, SIGNAL(startReading()), L1TWD, SLOT(startFired()), Qt::DirectConnection);

You are connecting the receiver and sender in different threads with direct connection, which will block the UI. Given that your slot execution gets stuck, this is expected. You have at least two issues here to solve.

- Use the default connection which will not block across threads, just inside the same thread. So, you would be writing something like this:

> connect(this, SIGNAL(startReading()), L1TWD, SLOT(startFired()));

- Secondly, you could make sure that your thread does not get stuck when there is some "network" problem.

For debugging purposes, please print out the current thread when having this kind of threading issues using [the following methods](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qthread.html#currentThread):

> [static] QThread * QThread::​currentThread()
>
> Returns a pointer to a QThread which manages the currently executing thread.

and [this](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qthread.html#currentThreadId):

> [static] Qt::HANDLE QThread::​currentThreadId()
>
> Returns the thread handle of the currently executing thread.
>
> Warning: The handle returned by this function is used for internal purposes and should not be used in any application code.
>
> Warning: On Windows, the returned value is a pseudo-handle for the current thread. It can't be used for numerical comparison. i.e., this function returns the DWORD (Windows-Thread ID) returned by the Win32 function getCurrentThreadId(), not the HANDLE (Windows-Thread HANDLE) returned by the Win32 function getCurrentThread().

Comment: Thank you! You have given better answer. I am sure there is a lot of issues with my code but I am still a beginner. The way you proposed worked now I think the moc does something behind the scene and generate problems for me.

Comment: @melanholly: printing the current threads will get us closer to solving your root cause.

Comment: @melanholly: I think your real issue may be [this](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qobject.html#moveToThread): `The object cannot be moved if it has a parent`. You have not shown the `TwidoDevice` constructor, but I assume you did set up a parent with one of your arguments.

Comment: No I don't have issue with the moving. Everything works well there. I mean the parent is set up.

Comment: @melanholly: that is the problem. It should not be set up!

Comment: @Ipapp I know that if I want to move the object to thread I shouldn't set the parent. That is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @melanholly: OK, so we checked everything by now in my understanding that could go wrong based on the pasted code, so I would assume the next would be to provide an SSCCE that reproduces the issue, at the very least the TwidoDevice constructor code. Just in case, you also printed out current thread ids and they differ?

Comment: @Ipapp well I've actually found out where was the problem when I use `Qt::AutoConnection`. The think is that I change very little code and the compiler does not compiles everything. Now when I don't see the result I am expecting I just go and delete the whole compiled directory and the I recompile the project. That seem to take care of the problem while connecting.

Comment: @melanholly: you need to get moc rerun, yeah. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a `Qt::DirectConnection` for your connection, which means the slot is called immediately, i.e on the same thread as the signal was fired. You can have a look at [the documentation for ConnectionType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). What you want to use is probably `Qt::QueuedConnection`, which executes the slot in the thread of the receiving object.

The best way though, as lpapp pointet out, is to let Qt decide what is best, and simply use `Qt::AutoConnection`, which is the default. It will use a `QueuedConnection` if signaling and receiving threads are different, and DirectConnection otherwise.

Comment: It would be even better to use auto (default) to be fair.

Comment: The default (auto) connection type is something that doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know why but when I don't pass this parameter the event doesn't get captured.

Comment: @melanholly: I think the main question for this thread why that is not working. Can you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: @MatthiasB Whell I worked fine with the `QueuedConnection` type. Thank you!

Comment: @ipapp
What is SSCCE and how can I provide one.

Comment: @melanholly: "I worked fine with the QueuedConnection type" -> IMHO, you are just hiding some issues that may come up later. You need to understand what your code is doing, not leaving things in that seems to work, but you do not understand why. At least, I would not call that a reliable piece of software. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) means to provide a small example that reproduces the issue for us. First, could you please print out the current threads where you connect as well as in the slot that is called? Are they the same or different?